# How to read single keystrokes without blocking the whole application?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, stdout, flush

Because I didn't find a better way to read keystrokes on command line I'm currently using `getch()`.

Unfortunately using `getch()` like this stops output on `stdout`:

```
while True:
    handle_keystroke(getch())
```

Pressing buttons triggers `handle_keystroke()` and `stdout` is being printed in the terminal - line by line for each keystroke.

Recommendations provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering/107717) didn't help.

What do I do wrong?

Btw: I do not *need* to use `getch()`. Is there a better way (e.g. using `select()`)?

**Update:** (changed the title)

All this becomes a problem only when you're using more than one thread. So it looks like `getch` (which is a non Python function) doesn't release the GIL, so all other threads are suspended, so not only `stdout` is affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a way to use `select` instead of `getch()`. The trick is to set the mode of `sys.stdout` to `cbreak`:

```
import select
import tty
import termios
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def cbreak(stream):
    """Set fd mode to cbreak"""
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(stream)
    tty.setcbreak(stream.fileno())
    yield
    termios.tcsetattr(stream, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)

with cbreak(sys.stdin):
    while True:
        select.select([sys.stdin], [], []) == ([sys.stdin], [], [])
        key = sys.stdin.read(1)
        handle_keystroke(key)
```